# Double VPN in Yosemite gone?

Tags: macos, vpn

I have upgraded my Macbook from Mavericks to Yosemite but after that double VPN is not working. I need to connect to local VPN first and from there to another VPN in order to connect to my company servers and I can connect to *either* of them differently but not from one to another. This used to work in Mavericks without any issues. Anyone know what has changed or how can I make it work as it was in Mavericks.

Thanks